# Insert multiple lines stored in a variable using sed in a file

Tags: linux, sed, in-place

Ubuntu
14.04

I want to insert few lines stored in a source file into a target file.
I'll read all those lines in a variable `$var` i.e. if I do `echo "${var}"` then it'll give me the following output -- which I want to add in my apache config file at a given line.

My exact source file (aka `${var}`)contents are:

```
        ## apppush proxying - get content from live site --##
        RewriteRule /apppush/hreflang/(.*) http://localhost:8081/hreflang.php?u=https://www.company.com/apppush/hreflang/$1 [P,L]

        RewriteCond /www/retaildb/companycom/us/branches/somebranch/us/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond /www/retaildb/companycom/us/branches/somebranch/us/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule ^/apppush/retail/(.*) /www/retaildb/companycom/us/branches/somebranch/us/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} [L]

        ## Search/GIGA apppush rewrite
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^/apppush/(.*)/search/(.*) /www/giga/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} [L]

        RewriteRule /apppush/(.*) https://www.company.com/apppush/$1 [P]
        ## END apppush Rewrites --##
```

To do the above operation using a simple example, I tried the following commands, which is giving me an error.

**For ex:** I want to add `${var}` which contains some values (3 lines total) into giga.txt file at line #3.

```
$ cat giga.txt
1
2
3
4
5
$ var="$(echo -e "333-444-555\n444-555-666\n555-666-777")"
$ echo "${var}"
333-444-555
444-555-666
555-666-777
gigauser@re-gigadev-s03-dev-2-32-3-rno:~/SVN_WS/repos/shenziconf$
$ sed -i "3i${var}" giga.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown command: `-'
```

I was expecting the output in giga.txt file as:

```
1
2
333-444-555
444-555-666
555-666-777
3
4
5
```

The end goal is to insert source file contents at line #3 in giga.txt (Target file / apache config file).

There are other ways to do this using a program to pick line# 1st-to-N, add source file contents, then line#s N+1 -to- EndOfFile to get the desired output but I trying to see if `sed` or `awk` can do this --OR--

**PS** For ex: The following command can successfully do similar operation (i.e. insert lines taken from a source file at a given location of the target file) **BUT** I'm looking how to do it via using a **$var**iable (if possible).

`sed -i "3r sourcefile.txt" targetfile.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since in the end you want to read from files and not a variable, you can use the `r` command directly: it reads a file and inserts it after the current line. So if you have `giga.txt` with

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and `source.txt` with

```
333-444-555
444-555-666
555-666-777
```

you can use this command:

```
$ sed '2r source.txt' giga.txt            
1
2
333-444-555
444-555-666
555-666-777
3
4
5
```

Notice that I've changed the line number to 2, as `r` appends *after* the line, whereas `i` inserts *before* the line.

---

If you *really* want to insert from a variable, you have to prepare it a bit: `i` requires that newlines are escaped with `\`, so if you do this

```
var=$(sed '$!s/$/\\/' source.txt)
```

you'll have a variable that looks as follows:

```
$ echo "$var"
333-444-555\
444-555-666\
555-666-777
```

and you can use this sed command:

```
$ sed "3i$var" giga.txt 
1
2
333-444-555
444-555-666
555-666-777
3
4
5
```

---

If you have GNU sed, you can combine these two approaches (hat tip [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep)'s comment): GNU sed can read standard input from the special file `/dev/stdin`, so you can use

```
sed '2r /dev/stdin' giga.txt <<< "$var"
```

or, if your shell doesn't support here strings like Bash does,

```
echo "$var" | sed '2r /dev/stdin' giga.txt
```

where `$var` doesn't need to have its newlines escaped.

Comment: Agree, I did find the solution but it'd be good if I can do the same using a variable where variable can be set directly from any other cmd output. Seems like `r` option is the way to go for now. OR I guess I have to create a random tmp file and use that with `r` while doing `sed`

Comment: @ArunSangal Do you want to modify the contents of the source file? Or why do you want to put it into a variable first?

Comment: @ArunSangal Updated with a solution that reads from a variable.

Comment: Yes, I took the example of file contents (as it was something similar to what I was trying to do) but I was planning to not read / create a file. It seems like using `3r srcfile` vs `3i $var` is what I'm comparing if the latter is possible

Comment: thanks a lot. Didn't know about `r` but now it's clear `i` vs `r`

Comment: to read directly from variable or pass output from another command, use `echo "$var" | sed '2r /dev/stdin'` ... works for GNU sed, not sure about other implementations

Comment: @Sundeep I think the availability of `/dev/stdin` depends on the system (and/or the shell), not on sed; to sed, it looks just like any file; see, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/portability-of-dev-stdout

Comment: I just checked the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands), it says `As a GNU sed extension, the special value /dev/stdin is supported for the file name, which reads the contents of the standard input`

Comment: @Sundeep Oh, nice! I'll add it.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding line #2 in giga.txt, can we have there a string-marker which will point us to where exactly to insert the new lines of text?

Comment: @Pourko You can use anything sed accepts as an address, for example a pattern: `/PATTERN/r filename`

Comment: So, it can be filename but not variable -- like the title of the original question?

Comment: @Pourko I'm not sure I understand - is your question about what is inserted (`filename`, above), or how the line where it's inserted is identified?

Comment: @Benjamin W. No, I can see how it works if the extra lines that need to be inserted are contained in a file. But the original question was asking if those extra lines can be contained in a Bash variable. (Never mind the roundabout solution of writing the contents of the variable to a file first.)

Comment: @Pourko The case where the string to be inserted is in a variable is covered in the last section.